# Compiling the code with opencv 2.4.10 in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, image-processing

After compiling the below code, i am finding error as mention below this code.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
    {
      printf( "No image data \n" );
      return -1;
    }

  namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Display Image", image );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Error during Building the project:

```
02:14:10 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Ohm ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\opencv\\build\\include" "-IC:\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o First.o "..\\First.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc10\\bin" -o Ohm.exe First.o -lopencv_core2410 -lopencv_ml2410 -lopencv_video2410 -lopencv_features2d2410 -lopencv_calib3d2410 -lopencv_objdetect2410 -lopencv_contrib2410 -lopencv_legacy2410 -lopencv_flann2410 -lopencv_core2410d -lopencv_highgui2410 -lopencv_highgui2410d -lopencv_imgproc2410 -lopencv_imgproc2410d 
First.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
First.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

02:14:14 Build Finished (took 3s.794ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

you **can't** use the prebuild msvc libs (-LC:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin) with mingw, it's a different compiler. get **cmake**, and **rebuild** the opencv libs using that. (sorry dear, no other way for you.)